# Installing R-package: RDCOMCLIENT in R Studio 4.1.2 - Fatal Error

Tags: r, package, rdcomclient

I'm trying to install the R package RDCOMCLIENT into R studio 4.1.2. I'm using R POSIT workbench to do this.

Here is the code I'm trying, which I found from here: https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/36#issuecomment-1044657643

```
dir.create("/conf/linkage/output/fileLocation/pq_allocation/scripts/okay")

remotes::install_github("BSchamberger/RDCOMClient", ref = "main", lib = "/conf/linkage/output/fileLocation/pq_allocation/scripts/okay")
```

And I am met with the following error:

```
In file included from COMError.cpp:1:0:
RCOMObject.h:23:10: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <windows.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/opt/R/4.1.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:175: COMError.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RDCOMClient’
* removing ‘/conf/linkage/output/fileLocation/pq_allocation/scripts/okay/RDCOMClient’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpoNQqvd/fileef484e587f/RDCOMClient_0.95-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Could someone please help me with this? I need the RDCOMCLIENT to send out automated messages via outlook.

I tried the above code in order to install the R package RDCOMCLIENT. I was expecting the package to be installed.

It was not installed.

I have tried inputting 'windows.h' into the location to no avail.

Comment: Where did you put windows.h? It would have to be in the same directory as RCOMObject.h

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean by windows.h.
I'm doing this at work, and they upgrades from R studio 3.6.1 to POSIT 4.1.2. I've not touched anything called windows.h

Comment: then how did you try "inputting it into the location"? .h files are C++ header files, but I don't know what windows.h does for this package.

Comment: RDCOMClient is a Windows-specific package while Posit Workbench can only be hosted on Linux.

Comment: I think the first part of margusl’s comment is correct but not the second point. The OP may be confusing version numbers  of Rstudio and R.

Comment: @IRTFM, from  _"/../ I'm using R POSIT workbench /../"_  and non-Windows paths in included code and error messages, I'd still assume OP is working on a remote [Workbench](https://docs.posit.co/rsw/requirements/) server hosted on Linux.

Comment: @margusl Yes, sorry. I'm logging on through the web browser on to R studio /Posit, on this version: RStudio Workbench 2022.07.2+576.pro12, “Spotted Wakerobin” (2a128b18). So this is Linux based,  and I can't install RDCOMClient, since that package is Windows-specific.... is there a Linux specific package to send outlook emails from the script?

Comment: @vly12 ,  I guess it mostly depends on IT-policy and infrastrucure; and there's a good chance that you'd get the best answer or at least few good pointers from your IT-team, perhaps do not ask them for specific R packages, instead check for services that are available for mail automation (they most likely want to know about any such attempts anyway).  I'd probably start with Microsoft365R - https://solutions.posit.co/connections/microsoft365/ .  And https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html#other-useful-packages-and-functions lists couple of  SMPT client libraries.

Comment: @vly12 I’m not sure there is such a thing as an “Outlook email “. Emails in general conform to an accepted protocol that any full-featured email client can read (on any modern OS.) There are several R packages that support email construction. Check out the CRAN Task Views page on “WebTechnologies”, in particular the Microsoft365R package.